# Ubuntu Nexus 7 Installer Fails Due to Bad Checksums

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 but the downloaded images always fail the checksum validation. I tried the manual installation but the link to the images is broken and poking around in the mirror yielded no results. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `phablet-flash` install method, works best!

Follow the [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) exactly!

If downloading is still causing a bad md5sum(for manual) close all you windows, restart your router & computer; your connection could be the issue. Maybe clear the browser cache.

Comment: I'm not downloading from the browser, the actual installer app is giving me the error. I was following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) wiki for installation

Comment: This is a quite different build.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment (Jun 29), you were attempting to install *Ubuntu **Desktop** for Nexus 7*.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation <-- **defunct instructions**

This repository has not been available for some time.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-preinstalled/current/ <-- **404 Not Found**

*This is a version of Ubuntu (12.04, 13.04) that demonstrates the standard Ubuntu desktop (and core components) on an **ASUS Nexus 7**. The code (and lessons learned) will be merged into the other 'phablet' (see below) stream at a later date. There is no current focus on this code at present.*

---

***Recommendation:***

Instead try the Ubuntu 'phablet' (phone/tablet) build.

This can be downloaded using the command line tool (**phablet-flash**), or manually.

See: ( from ***wiki.ubuntu.com*** )

[*Instructions for flashing a phone or tablet device with Ubuntu*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)